# cakephp authenticate user with repeated entries in the Database table (manual authentication?)

Tags: cakephp, authentication, manual

I'm creating an authentication system for a group of websites. The *problem* is that I have to use a pre-existing Database, which has a **users** table already full of entries, and that one user can have several accounts. Basically, a user has one account per website he has access to (it's not the best way to do this, but I can't change it). Each account is represented by an entry in the **users** table, with *login*, *password*, *name*... and the important field: **website_id**. This field tells the system what website that account has access to.

The big problem is that some users with more than one account have the exact same login/password information for all of them. For example, one user has 3 accounts:

- **account1:** login = charly / pwd = 1234 / name = Charles ... **website_id = 1**
- **account2:** login = charly / pwd = 1234 / name = Charles ... **website_id = 2**
- **account3:** login = charly / pwd = 1234 / name = Charles ... **website_id = 3**

So if he goes to the website that has **id = 2** and uses those credentials, he's granted access. If he goes to the website that has **id = 4**, he's denied access.

My problem is that since CakePHP does the login automatically, when a user tries to login, CakePHP checks **only the first** entry in the Database that matches the login/password submited in the form. So if a user is currently in the website with **website_id = 3** and tries to login, Cake finds the first entry (account1), compares its **website_id** (1 in this case) to the current website's id (3), and since they're different, the access is not granted, **but it should**. _Please note that the comparison of the website_id vs the account's website_id is already being made manually in the login() function_.

This how the login() function looks like now:

```
function login() {

    $userInfo = $this->Auth->user();

    if ( isset($userInfo) ) {

        if ($userInfo['User']['website_id'] == $this->website_id) { 

            //Users gets access to a website that he has an account for
        }
        else {
            //User is denied access because his account is not registered for the current website
            $this->Session->destroy();
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You don't have access to this website', true));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like is to be able to manually authorize the access to the current website by using the login/password submitted by the user to manually search in the *users* table, and if I find a match in one of the user accounts, grant the access, or otherwise deny access. To sum up, **avoid all the automagic of Auth's component.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Auth component's login method fails, control is transferred back to the custom login action (e.g. `UsersController::login()`). I've used this to authenticate using either username or email address, but it could be easily adapted for this purpose. Same idea, different criteria. I offered what I think is a [reasonably thorough response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280000/cakephp-auth-questions/7284312#7284312) (with code) to a similar question. It may help you as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I think that's sort of what I'm looking for. Just so I know that I got your code right, the statement where you're actually giving authorization to the user is `$this->Auth->login( $user )` right?

Comment: Correct. That "manually" authenticates the user. As another example, I call that immediately after a user registers so that s/he doesn't have to be sent to the login page to authenticate. Since s/he just registered, I feel pretty safe saving them the effort and logging them in directly.